# How to set scrolling speed of vim like set mouse=a when mouse=v?

Tags: vim, mouse, vimrc, xterm

I wonder how it's possible to set scrolling speed.

As is, when I scroll with my mouse in command or edit mode, it moves only one line at a time.

I prefer to move by example 3 line at a time. (speed up x3).

Any idea how to do this ? `:h ScrollWheelUp` confusing me.

I use a xterm like terminal.

vim 8.0.707 Debian9 X86_64

**Edit**:
I have to map 'button 4' to `ScrollWheelUp` and 'button 5' to `ScrollWheelDown` (seen values from `xev`)

Comment: are you using a gui or a terminal? In my gui version, Scrolling using the mouse already scrolls by 3 lines as documented at `:h ScrollWheelUp`.

Comment: an xterm like one, only one at a time

Comment: I have to map 'button 4' to ScrollWheelUp and 'button 5' to ScrollWheelDown (seen button values from xev)